# How to install mysql using binary src file for cygwin?

Tags: mysql, cygwin

I am trying to set up mysql on cygwin, since I have automation task so I need command line other than gui.

I downloaded the file from mysql website and it has no configure file when I untar it. As below:

[image: no configure file]

I was supposed to type,

```
./configure 
make 
make install
```

but now I am stuck, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.5 is built using CMake so you would instead do:

```
cmake .
make
make install
```

More information in the MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/installing-source-distribution.html.

That said, Cygwin does have a binary MySQL package which is easily installed and might save you some trouble. Run Cygwin setup.exe and look under 'databases' for 'mysql' and 'mysqld'.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is there a particular reason you need to compile MySQL from scratch or can you use the Cygwin-provided binaries?

Comment: That's not a very informative error. I strongly recommend you use the Cygwin-provided MySQL.